# PHP datepicker calendar

Tags: php, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

First of all, let me tell you what i am trying to do. I am trying to do a datepicker where information on the particular dates would be display out when the user click on the dates.

**calendar.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0, 
        maxDate: 30, //The maximal date that can be selected, i.e. + 1 month, 1 week, and 3 days from "now"
        showAnim: "bounce",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'my_ajax_stuff.php',
                data: {date : dateText},
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById("in").innerHTML = response;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my **my_ajax_stuff.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE startdate={$_post['dateText']}";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>startdate</th>
<th>enddate</th>
</tr>
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['startdate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['enddate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

The problem now is, the datepicker seems to appear fine. But when i click on the dates, no data is being displayed out. I have got a feeling that it is my php which is causing the problem. If anyone could give me some direction on how i should write it... i am really greatful for it. Many thanks.

Comment: It's out of topic but are your code safe from SQLInjection?

Comment: Nope is not. and would be nice if it is related to the topic...

Comment: In `my_ajax_stuff.php` you are using `$_post['dateText']` instead of `$_post['date']` and you should add an element in your `calendar.html` file with `id="in"`. Anyway, you are importing too much js and css file, you just need `jquery.js`, `jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.css`. You need initialization code for datepicker just once and maybe you can do this inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at your PHP code and you should be able to spot the missing double quote after the first echo. Here is a corrected version that may help you move forward.

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE startdate={$_post['dateText']}";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>startdate</th>
<th>enddate</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['startdate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['enddate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: it was nice of you. but the datepicker doesnt seems to react to this php file.